# How do Instruction Fetch and Memory Access co-operate without an Instruction Cache?

Tags: riscv

I've been looking into RISC-V and the RISC pipeline, and realised that a Memory Access can happen at the same time as the Instruction Fetch. Assuming that it is a fairly basic implementation without any cache, this is a hazard. I did a bit of digging and found [this](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/%7Eprabhu/Tutorial/PIPELINE/structHaz.html). It talks about inserting a bubble/stall, which makes sense, but how would one go about that? I thought about using a NOP, but the IF to actually grab that would still cause contention. Is the stall inserted by the Load/Store instruction? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

In computer architecture, there are two kind of architectures - Harvard and von Neumann. In Harvard architecture,instruction and data memory are separate but von Neumann has same instruction and data memory resulting in structural hazards.

Generally in RISC-V, we use separate instruction and data memory to avoid structural hazard. As in, if you have only data cache, architecturally you should fetch instruction directly from the memory.

Comment: "...if you have only data cache..." Sorry, I should clarify. I meant no cache at all, just direct memory access. I forgot about regular data caches while writing; I'll edit the question.